# swfobject width

Tags: width, swfobject

I want to modify the width of an swf object;
here is the code: 
index.php:

```
<div id="websiteid">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {
        quality: "high",
        wmode: "window",
        devicefont: "false",
        allowscriptaccess: "always",
        bgcolor: "#000000",
        allowFullScreen: "true",
        scale: "noScale", 
        salign: "lt", 
        menu: "false"
    };
    var attributes = {
        id: "flash"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF("template.swf", "websiteid", "520", "600", "9.0.0",
    "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

So, I modify the "520" with "800" for example, and if upload on my server nothing is changed, also if I open 
firebug and modify it it works. 
What could be the problem ? I've tried also to upload on other server and same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in caching. Change file names.

Comment: do you mean to change index.php to test.php for example  ?

Comment: Name of .swf file (ie. template1.swf ...)

Comment: I've tried this also, and the same issue... it can be from my ftp software ? I use FileZilla ...

Comment: It's very strange because if I look on a web browser I don't see the changes in my code, but if I download the file from FTP and open it in a text editor I see the changes...